# PHPUnit throws "Test framework quit unexpectedly" when running a feature test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm running PHP 7.2 (WAMP 3.1), PHPUnit 8.2.3, PhpStorm 2019.1 but I don't think it's a configuration problem seeing as though my previous tests from the same file seem to be working as expected and all the tests pass. Here's the feature test that "fails" and accompanying code.

The test:

```
/**@test*/
    public function a_user_can_view_a_project(){
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $project = factory('App\Project')->create();
        $this->get('/projects/'.$project->id)
             ->assertSee('title')
             ->assertSee('description');
    }
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/projects/{project}', 'ProjectsController@show');
```

The controller function:

```
public function show(Project $project){
        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }
```

The migration:

```
class CreateProjectsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('projects');
    }
}
```

The factory:

```
$factory->define(Project::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing `/**@test*/` to `/** @test */` (added spaces) before the test.